# How to use Kotlin Android Extensions with ViewStub properly?

Tags: android, kotlin-android-extensions, viewstub

Does the extensions have a magic to call inflated view? As far as I see, I should break the harmony of code and call `findViewById`.

The intent was to inflate `layout_ongoingView` layout at sometime, and make hidden, and visible again based on scenario.

```
<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/viewStubOngoing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/ongoingView"
    android:layout="@layout/layout_ongoingView" />
```

And codes

```
override fun hideOngoingPanel() {
    if (viewStubOngoing !is ViewStub) {
        findViewById(R.id.ongoingView).visibility = View.GONE
    }
}

override fun showOngoingPanel() {
    if (viewStubOngoing !is ViewStub) {
        findViewById(R.id.ongoingView).visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        viewStubOngoing.inflate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution besides the ugly findViewById? Facing the same issue now...